# "Wait" gate throws an error "NotImplementedError: ('No decomposition rules defined for ', 'wait')"

Tags: programming, qiskit

My Quantum circuit contains ["Wait" Gate](https://qiskit.org/documentation/autodoc/qiskit.extensions.simulator.wait.html).  When I try to execute it (`qasm_simulator` or `unitary-simulator`), it throws an error . **NotImplementedError: ('No decomposition rules defined for ', 'wait')**.

**Question**
1.How to resolve the error?
2.What is the unit of `t` specified in "wait" gate arguments?

Dev Env

Anaconda (python 3.6)
qiskit 0.7.3
qiskit-aer 0.1.1
qiskit-terra 0.7.0

OS
Mac v10.14

Qiskit installation by `pip install qiskit`

**Minimal Example**

```
from qiskit import QuantumRegister, ClassicalRegister, QuantumCircuit
from qiskit.extensions.standard import RXGate, RYGate, RZGate, U3Gate
from qiskit.extensions.simulator import wait


from qiskit import execute, BasicAer, Aer

qubit = QuantumRegister(1, 'qubit')
circuit = QuantumCircuit(qubit)

circuit.x(qubit)
circuit.wait(1e-6, qubit)
circuit.rx(3.1416, qubit)

backend = Aer.get_backend('statevector_simulator')
job = execute(circuit, backend)
result = job.result()
outputstate = result.get_statevector(circuit, decimals=3)
print(outputstate)
```

If I comment the line `circuit.wait(...)` it runs fine. I tried the `qasm_simulator` with counts/measurements (same error)

Comment: Thanks for the question. Could you post a minimal example of the problem? Also, are you trying to execute it or Aer of BasicAer?

Comment: @JamesWootton - minimal example added to original question. To answer your question, I tried BasicAer too - with same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `wait` command has now been deprecated, which is probably why it's causing you problems.

Instead you can use the identity gate `iden`. You should also use barriers either side so that the compiler doesn't remove it.

```
circuit.x(qubit)
circuit.barrier(qubit)
circuit.iden(qubit)
circuit.barrier(qubit)
circuit.rx(3.1416, qubit)
```

This causes a delay for a the same time as a single `u2` gate, which is the time needed for a single $\pi/2$-pulse (see [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1707.03429)).

Comment: Well, the documentation and the stable code still show `wait` as available. I am accepting your answer because it seems there is no other reason and `master` branch does not seem to have that function anymore and I have to switch to the solution you showed anyway. Thanks